# A misconception in variable separation method for 2-D heat equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

While solving the PDF of 2-D heat equation
$U_t= C (U_{xx}+U_{yy})$, via classic separation method to set $U(x,y,t)=X(x)Y(y)T(t)$, then by plugging into the PDE, we would have the following expression: $$\frac{T'}{CT}=\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}= \lambda\tag{1}$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant. To further analyze steady state where $t\rightarrow \infty$ and $  T'= 0$, it seems right to have:

$$\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=0\tag{2}$$

My question is,  according to $(1)$, the constant $\lambda$ should be a fixed number that satisfies B.C. & I.C. for all $t,x$ and $y$.  But $(2)$ seems to say equation $(1)$ has an exception as $t \rightarrow\infty$, and the fix number shrinks to zero instead. This seems paradox to me because I feel $(1)$ shall be hold for any $t$ without exception. Hope my misconception can be pointed out.

Comment: $T'\to 0$ does not mean $\lambda\to 0$.

Comment: If $T' \to 0$ does not mean $\lambda \to 0$, then how could (2) stand? The $\lambda$ seems to have eigen-value sense, and I kind of think it is not something can be changed under any circumstance.Although it seems intuitive to have  $U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0$ because of $U_t=0$ as $t \to 0$, but it still struggles me by my inference on (1) and (2) via variable separation method.

Comment: $T\to 0$ to compensate for the change in $T'$ in order to preserve $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. So if presume $T=T_0e^{C \lambda t}$ and C<0, then $\frac{T'}{CT}=\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{T'}{CT}=\lambda$. Maybe this is the point: if $\lambda$ is gonna preserved anyhow, how can we therefore have zero instead of $\lambda$ in (2)?

Comment: That's exactly the point. You don't.